# Access Code not working for check if a user have permission - RBAC Yii2

Tags: yii2, rbac

i have a problem verifying the permissions that a user has on the actions (Exm: index, create, update, etc.) within the controller, I use the following code to verify the permissions that the user has:

My Controller:

```
backend/modules/content/controllers/ArticleController.php

$behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {

                    $module     =   Yii::$app->controller->module->id;
                    $action     =   Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
                    $controller =   Yii::$app->controller->id;
                    $route      =   "$module/$controller/$action";
                    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
                    if (\Yii::$app->user->can($route)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

With this code I get the route (Exm:content/article/index) which will be validated to know if you have the permission.

**Updating**

I have noticed that the problem is generated in `'as globalAccess'` `(backend/config/web.php)`, when I deactivate the global access it can validate the permissions, but when I have global access all users have full access, but disabling it brings other problems .

```
'as globalAccess' => [
    'class' => common\behaviors\GlobalAccessBehavior::class,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'controllers' => ['sign-in'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?'],
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'controllers' => ['sign-in'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
            'actions' => ['logout'],
        ],
        [
            'controllers' => ['site'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?', '@'],
            'actions' => ['error'],
        ],
        [
            'controllers' => ['debug/default'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

the problem is that validation does not work, the only way it works is to add a rule in global access that allows me to grant permissions to roles, but it would be default:

```
        [
            'controllers' => ['article'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['administrator'],
        ],
        [
            'controllers' => ['article'],
            'allow' => false,
        ],
```

or go adding the function in each action `Yii::$app->user->can(..)` in each action

`if (\Yii::$app->user->can('content/article/index')) {
   .. code index ..
} else {

   throw new ForbiddenHttpException
}`

In the ideal case, you don't have to be adding the function `Yii::$app->user->can(..)` to each action or add a default rule in global access.I hope can support me

Comment: Have you debugged it? Does it return `true` when it supposed to? Add `return false;` at the end as well.

Comment: I have already seen the problem is generated in 'as globalAccess' (backend/config/web.php), when I disable global access you can validate the permissions, but when I have global access all users have full access, but disabling it brings me other problems.